# Lucene text search failing for names ending with a non-alphabet

Tags: java, lucene, webmethods, query-parser

In my Webmethods application I need to implement a Search functionality and I had done it with Lucene. But the search is not retrieving results when I am searching for file with title ending in something other than alpabet.for eg:- doc1.txt  or new$.txt
In the code below when i try to **print queryCmbd** its printing  Search Results>>>>>>>title:"doc1 txt" (contents:doc1 contents:txt).when I search for a string like doc.txt, the result is Search Results>>>>>>>title:"doc.txt" contents:doc.txt. What should be done in order to parse these kinds of strings(like doc1.txt,new$.txt)?

```
 public java.util.ArrayList<DocNames> searchIndex(String querystr,
                String path, StandardAnalyzer analyzer) {
            String FIELD_CONTENTS = "contents";
            String FIELD_TITLE = "title";
            String queryStringCmbd = null;

            queryStringCmbd = new String();

            String queryFinal = new String(querystr.replaceAll(" ", " AND "));
            queryStringCmbd = FIELD_TITLE + ":\"" + queryFinal + "\" OR "
                    + queryFinal;


            try {

                FSDirectory directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(path));

                Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, FIELD_CONTENTS,
                        analyzer).parse(querystr);

                Query queryCmbd = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,
                        FIELD_CONTENTS, analyzer).parse(queryStringCmbd);

                int hitsPerPage = 10;
                IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(directory);
                IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

                TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(
                        hitsPerPage, true);
                indexSearcher.search(queryCmbd, collector);
                ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;

                System.out
                        .println("Search Results>>>>>>>>>>>>"
                                + queryCmbd);

                docNames = new ArrayList<DocNames>();
                for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; ++i) {
                    int docId = hits[i].doc;
                    Document d = indexSearcher.doc(docId);
                    DocNames doc = new DocNames();
                    doc.setIndex(i + 1);
                    doc.setDocName(d.get("title"));
                    doc.setDocPath(d.get("path"));
                    if (!(d.get("path").contains("indexDirectory"))) {
                        docNames.add(doc);
                    }
                }

                indexReader.flush();
                indexReader.close();
                indexSearcher.close();
                return docNames;
            } catch (CorruptIndexException e) {
                closeIndex(analyzer);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                closeIndex(analyzer);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                closeIndex(analyzer);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact you're using `StandardAnalyzer`. If you read its [javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0-ALPHA/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html), it tells that it's using `StandardTokenizer` for token splitting. This means phrases like `doc1.txt` will be split into `doc1` and `txt`.

If you want to match the entire text, you need to use `KeywordAnalyzer`- **both for indexing and searching**. The code below displays the difference: using `StandardAnalyzer` tokens are `{"doc1", "txt"}` and using `KeywordAnalyzer` the only token is `doc1.txt`.

```
    String foo = "foo:doc1.txt";
    StandardAnalyzer sa = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_34);
    TokenStream tokenStream = sa.tokenStream("foo", new StringReader(foo));
    while (tokenStream.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println(tokenStream.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class).term());
    }

    System.out.println("-------------");

    KeywordAnalyzer ka = new KeywordAnalyzer();
    TokenStream tokenStream2 = ka.tokenStream("foo", new StringReader(foo));
    while (tokenStream2.incrementToken()) {
        System.out.println(tokenStream2.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class).term());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that really worked! but can we use KeywordAnalyzer to find files having content like 'X X X X X X X X X X X X' or in case of search string containing spaces? I tried but failed to get results? What can be done in such cases? Kindly help

Comment: You need to provide more details, and the best thing to do is to open a new question and show the code. Also, if this answer had helped, you might want to accept it, otherwise people will stop providing you answers.